# Loops problems in R

Tags: r, statistics

I am going to generate a vector `v` from `0.0` to `1.0` in R by using following code. 
However, `v` only goes to `0.99`.

```
> s <- 0.0; v <- numeric();
> while ( s <= 1 ){
+    v <- append(v, s)
+    s <- s + 0.01
+ }
> v
  [1] 0.00 0.01 0.02 0.03 0.04 0.05 0.06 0.07 0.08 0.09 0.10 0.11 0.12 0.13 0.14
 [16] 0.15 0.16 0.17 0.18 0.19 0.20 0.21 0.22 0.23 0.24 0.25 0.26 0.27 0.28 0.29
 [31] 0.30 0.31 0.32 0.33 0.34 0.35 0.36 0.37 0.38 0.39 0.40 0.41 0.42 0.43 0.44
 [46] 0.45 0.46 0.47 0.48 0.49 0.50 0.51 0.52 0.53 0.54 0.55 0.56 0.57 0.58 0.59
 [61] 0.60 0.61 0.62 0.63 0.64 0.65 0.66 0.67 0.68 0.69 0.70 0.71 0.72 0.73 0.74
 [76] 0.75 0.76 0.77 0.78 0.79 0.80 0.81 0.82 0.83 0.84 0.85 0.86 0.87 0.88 0.89
 [91] 0.90 0.91 0.92 0.93 0.94 0.95 0.96 0.97 0.98 0.99
>
```

So I take a look on `s` and the logic in the while loop. 
I discovered something mistery...

```
> s <= 1
[1] FALSE
> s == 1
[1] FALSE
> s
[1] 1
```

It is assumed that `s` should be `1.01`, but it only goes to `1`... 
So we know `s` is `1`, but why it is not equal to `1`?

*(I am new to R, sorry for asking stupid question.)*

Comment: The reason `s <= 1` and `s == 1` fail is due to floating point error.

Comment: Skimming the FAQ is often a worthwhile investment of time: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the built in R function `seq`?

```
> seq(0,1,.01)
  [1] 0.00 0.01 0.02 0.03 0.04 0.05 0.06 0.07 0.08 0.09 0.10 0.11 0.12 0.13 0.14
 [16] 0.15 0.16 0.17 0.18 0.19 0.20 0.21 0.22 0.23 0.24 0.25 0.26 0.27 0.28 0.29
 [31] 0.30 0.31 0.32 0.33 0.34 0.35 0.36 0.37 0.38 0.39 0.40 0.41 0.42 0.43 0.44
 [46] 0.45 0.46 0.47 0.48 0.49 0.50 0.51 0.52 0.53 0.54 0.55 0.56 0.57 0.58 0.59
 [61] 0.60 0.61 0.62 0.63 0.64 0.65 0.66 0.67 0.68 0.69 0.70 0.71 0.72 0.73 0.74
 [76] 0.75 0.76 0.77 0.78 0.79 0.80 0.81 0.82 0.83 0.84 0.85 0.86 0.87 0.88 0.89
 [91] 0.90 0.91 0.92 0.93 0.94 0.95 0.96 0.97 0.98 0.99 1.00
```

The reason you get `FALSE` for `s<= 1` is because you're trying to compare an integer to a floating point number. Floating point numbers are [inherently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Representable_numbers.2C_conversion_and_rounding) [imprecise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) , and will make equality comparisons difficult.

In your specific case, adding the final `.01` to `s` bumped it up enough that it was just over 1, causing your loop to terminate one iteration before you expected.

This is part of the reason that it's a good habit to use R's built in functions for things like this, as they'll handle the corner cases for you (and will also be faster in most cases.)

Comment: Because I am not fully familiar with R, so I create it by my own :P

Comment: Reading through "An Introduction to R" (http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html) might help you. Definitely use `seq` for this though.

Comment: But can you explain why `s <= 1` is `FALSE`?

Comment: @EricHo Yes. Because `seq` is presumably adding some number that's *ever so slightly greater than 1/100* together 100 times. The resultant sum is greater than 1.

Comment: @Wilduck -- And for the sequence to behave as the OP expects it, `(1:100)/100` (or `seq(1,100,by=1)/100`) will work slightly better.

Answer (score 1):

This phenomenon is frequently occurring when you try to compare the float value with very precise decimals.

In your case, you try to compare 1, actually it's larger than 1 a little bit. So, when you try to compare with s<=1 is always false.

[See more information of floating point errors here](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/11/floatingpoint-errors-explained.html)